# one model that connects two entries of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Dear all (first post on stackoverflow),

I would like to connect two entries of the Model Molecule via the Model Interaction and build synchronous association.

When I create an interaction between say molecule 1 and molecule 2 by Interaction.create(molecule_id=1, partner_id=2), the interaction is only added to molecule 1.
I would like to have the interaction being saved to each of the molecules. 
A workaround by adding subsequently adding an interaction to molecule 2 with swapped id parameters does not make sense.

Model Molecule:

```
class Molecule < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :interactions
  has_many :partners, through: :interactions

end
```

Model Interaction:

```
class Interaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :molecule
  belongs_to :partner, :class_name => 'Molecule'

end
```

Interactions Migration File:

```
class CreateInteractions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :interactions do |t|
     t.belongs_to :molecule
     t.belongs_to :host,  class: 'Molecule'
     t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I hope the post is correct at this position and well formated. Please tell me if I am supposed to provide more information. I surely I hope one of you can help me finding a decent solution for that problem. Thanks and best regards,
Stephan

Comment: well, that's how it works. i assume that there is another way to model it. i dont know about your business-domain, but if you are somewhere in the host-guest chemistry, then you could model a complex that has a list of molecules.

Comment: Well, good guess!^^. It does not matter actually, thinking of a chemical reaction a 1-1 connection (bidirectional) is always established in a bimolecular reaction/interaction. Thanks for your comment, but I do not see how this would solve my problem. Maybe enlighten me by a code example.